# Cannot change cursor type on Windows 10

Tags: microsoft-windows, cursor

I've used emacs on Windows 10 for a year. Recently, my "box" cursor in emacs has become a thin vertical line.

I have tried setting the variable "cursor-type", but this no longer seems to have any effect.

I have found a short comment that emacs might be detecting assistive technology (like speech recognition) and using a system cursor.  See [here](https://help-gnu-emacs.gnu.narkive.com/nzvU1H6B/emacs-24-cursor-shape-is-now-i).  I've tried turning off speech recognition in Windows, but that doesn't seem to fix the cursor in emacs.

Is there a way to force emacs to use a box cursor instead of a Windows native cursor? (If this is indeed my problem.)

Comment: Can you provide a recipe to reproduce the problem, starting with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to perhaps find the culprit.

Comment: Even with `emacs -Q`, the cursor is a thin vertical line.  I used to have a block cursor, but something has changed in how emacs and Windows interact.

Comment: Maybe do `M-x report-emacs-bug`, to report it as a bug. Alternatively, you can copy the Emacs version and build info provided automatically for the bug report into your question here. (Or else copy what you see from `M-: (emacs-version)`, `C-h v emacs-build-system`, `C-h v emacs-repository-version`, `C-h v system-configuration-options`, and `C-h v system-configuration-features`.) Perhaps such info will help someone answer the question.

Comment: I guess you also made sure screen magnify is turned off? I see that too is mentioned in the post you cited. (Good find of that post, BTW.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47299632/windows-emacs-25-3-cursor-type).

```
;; Disable the system cursor caused by screen reader etc.
(setq w32-use-visible-system-caret nil)
```

Helps to know that you need to search for "caret" instead of "cursor".

Comment: I checked your answer and it works. Perhaps accepting your answer?